# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in cv::Mat line 522

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a function that returns smaller parts of an image. I am using the function Rect() for cutting.
I get no error  when debugging but when I try to execute the function I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\opencv\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 522

Here is my code:

```
void divideImage(Mat input_image, vector<Mat> output_images, int width_fraction, int height_fraction ) {

int width = input_image.rows / width_fraction - 1;
int height = input_image.cols / height_fraction - 1;

    for (int w = 0; w < input_image.rows; w+=width) {
        for (int h = 0; h < input_image.cols; h+=height) {
            Mat tiles = input_image(Rect(w, h, width, height));
            output_images.push_back(tiles);
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Get parameters from command line
CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
String image_path1 = parser.get<String>(0);

    if (image_path1.empty())
    {
        help();
        return -1;
    }

// Load image 
cv::Mat img_1_rgb = imread(image_path1, 1);
Mat img_1;
cvtColor(img_1_rgb, img_1, CV_BGR2GRAY);

vector<Mat> output_images(4);

divideImage(img_1, output_images, 2, 2);
```

Seems like my ROI is somehow out of bounds.

With the help of api55 I present the correct loop:

```
 void divideImage(Mat input_image, vector<Mat> output_images, int width_fraction, int height_fraction ) {

 int width = (input_image.cols / width_fraction) - 1;
 int height = (input_image.rows / height_fraction) - 1;

for (int w = 0; w < input_image.cols-width_fraction*width_fraction; w+=width) {
    for (int h = 0; h < input_image.rows-height_fraction*height_fraction; h+=height) {
        Mat tiles = input_image(Rect(w, h, width, height));
        output_images.push_back(tiles);
        //cout << w << " " << h << " " << width << " " << height << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: print this `Rect(w, h, width, height)` every time and see what the problem is, maybe  `width`  or  `height`  less 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Let me give you an example:

Lets say your image is of a size of 640x480

now lets calculate the width variable of your function with the same parameters you use

```
int width = 640 / 2 - 1; // 319
```

now lets start our loop, for the first time `w=0` and you get something like

```
Rect(0, 0, 319, 239)
```

Then for the next width iteration you will have `w+=width` which is `w=319` and something like

```
Rect(319, 0, 319, 239)
```

The second iteration will have `w+=width` again which is `w=638`, as you clearly can see 638 is less than the rows of my image (640), thus it will try to do

```
Rect(638, 0, 319, 239)
```

which will jump the assert mentioned, since

> roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols

will be translated to

```
638 + 319 <= 640
```

which is false.

You have to change how it is looping, also in the best case scenario which it works, you will loose n columns/rows, being n the number of divisions. (you can try to put a limit like

```
input_image.rows - width_fraction
```

in the for loop check, if you do not care for the dropped columns.

Further suggestions, learn how to use the debugger!! it should jump on the assert, unless that you run it in release mode, if not, something is wrong, the code should fail always.

Comment: Another error was that I used rows and cols the wrong way (width refers to input_image.cols). I changed it in my post.